# Serial connection in WSL 1 works in cu but not minicom/screen

Tags: serial-port, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to connect to a serial device (com4) with WSL 1 Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from Windows Store.

I did:

**stty -F /dev/ttyS4 1152000 cs8 -cstopb -parenb**

**sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyS4**

**sudo cu -l /dev/ttyS4**

and it works, where I can see the command prompt of the device's interface.

However when I tried:

**minicom -c on -w -b 1152000 -D /dev/ttyS4**

and

**screen /dev/ttyS4 1152000**

all I get is gibberish.

I am really stumped on this. Any idea why it works with cu but not with minicom or screen?

Comment: Just in case, are you sure that the Baud rate is `1152000`, NOT `115200`?

Comment: Yes it is 1152000

Answer (score 0):

hardware flow control should be set to NO in minicom

Comment: This is not an aswer, post it as a comment